# Can I get steps to connect my grails to MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, grails

Please help me with steps to connect grails to SQLserver2008.

I have been trying with setting over grails app-config.properties and DataSource.groovy file too.

File 1 : app-config.properties

```
dataSource.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
dataSource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
dataSource.url=jdbc:sqlserver:thin:@xxx.xxx.x.:1433;databaseName=xxxx
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=P@ssw0rd1x
```

File 2 : Config.groovy

```
activiti {
processEngineName = "activiti-engine-default"
      databaseType = "sql"
      databaseSchemaUpdate = true
      deploymentName = appName
```

Comment: would you mind showing your settings and the error you are getting

Comment: Im new to grails. Hence im unsure if my approach is correct. So can i expect steps to connect grails-mssql2008  instead?

Comment: @Satya provided some more details

Comment: and you have the driver in class path right ?

Comment: @Satya 1. Im using sqljdbc4.jar placed in grails-app/lib
        2. Is the above jar correct?
3. What are different ways to set the classpath here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work with the mssql-2008, but for my application connection with mssql 2012 I have used following changes to connect it with the database:

Step1: On the datasource.groovy changed the datasource to:

```
dataSource {

       pooled = true
       driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
       url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=<Db-Name>"
       username = "sa"
       password = "root"
       dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
       logSql = true
   }
```

Step2. Then I have placed jtds-1.2.5.jar and jtidy-r938.jar files in the lib folder.

And I think it should connect with the mssql db, for me it worked with sql server 2012, hope it should also work with 2008.

I think need not to make any other change anywhere else. :)

Comment: have had changed to the same settings later mentioned by you here.However , the run-app is stopping with exception    

"caused by activitiException : 'org/activiti/db/create/activiti.sql.create.engine.sql